# Js помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

Есть два выражения

```
let a = [ numA = 1 , numB = 2 ]
let b = { numC : 1 , numD : 2}
```

Принципиальная разница в чем ? Я понимаю что один массив другой обьект,
мне не понятно почему я могу так сделать

```
console.log( numA );
```

а должен

```
console.log( a.numA );
```

так меня компилятор вообще далеко посылает
я чет сильно туплю (отредактировано)

Comment: "почему я могу так сделать" --- **так** - это **как**?

Comment: и почему ты должен сделать `a.numA` ? Кому должен? В чём вообще вопрос - не ясно. Что ты пытаешься сделать - не ясно.

Comment: Выражение `numA = 1` создаёт глобальную переменную numA и возвращает значение 1, выражение `numB = 2` создаёт глобальную переменную numB и возвращает значение 2. Соответственно, этот код примерно эквивалентен коду `globalThis.numA = 1; globalThis.numB = 2; let a = [1, 2]`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450401/%d0%9c%d0%90%d0%a1%d0%a1%d0%98%d0%92%d0%ab-%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d0%91%d0%ac%d0%9a%d0%95%d0%a2%d0%ab - дубликат вопроса, еще и разные аккаунты у участника.

Comment: @Daniil  наоборот, тот вопрос дубликат этого

Answer (score 1):

Все достаточно просто, js объектно-ориентированный язык. `let a = [ numA = 1 , numB = 2 ]` - данное выражение не создает ассоциативный массив как `let b = { numC : 1 , numD : 2}`. Функция присвоения `numA = 1` создает локальную переменную `numA` и присваивает ей число, но так же она возвращает само это число как return, то есть `(numA=1) == 1) is true`. То есть первое выражение делает `let a = [1, 2]` но также оно создает и локальные переменные `var numA=1; var numB=2`. К массиву, если что, можно обратиться по индексу `a[0]` выдаст `1`. Получается что простыми словами мы создали обычный массив и возле него еще и переменные, и это было бы как выражение:

```
//это выражение
let a = [ numA = 1 , numB = 2 ]

//равняется этому выражению
let numA=1
let numB=2
let a = [numA, numB]
```